# "image_picker" package in flutter opening random folder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use "image_picker" package in my flutter project to pick images from android device's gallery.

But this is opening some random folder by default while trying to select images instead of recent or downloads folder.

How can I configure image picker to open a specific folder every time? For example- Downloads folder.

This is the flutter code I am using for a button for choosing image.

````
GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          _animationController.stop();

                          /// waiting for a image to be picked from the local
                          /// storage
                          XFile? image = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 100);

                          setState(() {
                            /// get the file path of the local file the user has picked.
                            /// setting the state to show the uploading effect
                            _image = File(image!.path);
                          });

                          /// uploading the image
                          await _profileProviderRead.sendImage(image, widget.photoAlbumName, context);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.h),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: kGradient1,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.r),
                          ),
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.add_rounded,
                            color: kWhiteColor,
                            size: 32,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    The "image_picker" package doesn't have a built-in option to directly open a specific folder like the Downloads folder.
    
    However, you can indirectly achieve this behavior by using a file picker library alongside the "image_picker" package. The file picker library allows you to pick files from specific directories, including the Downloads folder.

1.) Add the "file_picker" package to your pubspec.yaml file.
2.)Modify your button's onTap function to use the file picker to open the Downloads folder:

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () async {
    _animationController.stop();

    /// Use the file picker to open the Downloads folder and pick a file.
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);

    if (result != null) {
      /// Get the file path of the selected file and create a File object from it.
      String? imagePath = result.files.single.path;
      if (imagePath != null) {
        setState(() {
          _image = File(imagePath);
        });
      }

      /// Upload the image.
      await _profileProviderRead.sendImage(_image, widget.photoAlbumName, context);
    } else {
      // User canceled the file picking.
    }
  },
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.h),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: kGradient1,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.r),
    ),
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.add_rounded,
      color: kWhiteColor,
      size: 32,
    ),
  ),
),


By using the "file_picker" package with type: FileType.image, you can open the file picker directly in the Downloads folder or any other folder containing images. The user can then select an image, and you can proceed with the rest of your logic to upload the image.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adarsh. This is working as I needed.

Comment: Welcome!so please accept it.